# Create an confirm box for external links to a certain class, maybe with document.getElementByCLassName?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and want a function that activates when you click on a link that leads outside the website. It should alert that you are about to leave the page and bring up a box that says "Do you really want to leave the site?" with response alternatives "OK" and "Cancel".

I've managed to do this like this (with an img that works like a link):

```
HTML:
<a href="http://www.urbanoutfitters.com" 
onClick="return confirm('Do you really want to leave the site?')" 
class="relaterade"> <img src="img5.jpg"/> </a>
```

I wonder if you can make a function so all in the class "relaterade" gets this confirm box instead of writing this on every single link. Maybe with document.getElementByCLassName? I want all JavaScript in a separate document.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element collection by doing document.getElementsByClassName. You must then loop through the collection and set the onclick event handler

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass');
for (var element in elements) {
    elements[element].onclick = function() {
        return confirm('are you sure?');
    }
}
```

this is from the top of my head, so dont know if it works for sure.

You could do this more easily with a library like jQuery though, cause IE < 9.0 will fail on the getElementsByClassName function